# should I move on to entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqldatareader

I use visual studio 2005 , but recently I've heard that there is a new technology which called `entity framework` .. should I move on and use it instead of using the usual `SqlDataReader` !!

 
the most important thing to me is  the performance , note that I get the data from the DB using DataReader and return it as a generic List .. 
 
any suggestion .. thanx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SqlDataReader` and the `Entity Framework` are two completely different approaches to access your data. With `SqlCommand`s, you yourself write the SQL queries. With an O/R mapping technology such as the `Entity Framework`, the relational database structure is mapped to objects whose properties you access, e.g. Linq to Entities. Note that the O/R mapping approach is *not* about speed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in `VS 2005`. I think you can't use Entity FrameWork. For that you required 2008 and .NET 3.5 SP1. Entity Framework has some issues. If you are going with Entity Framework; go with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0. This will be a better option.

Latest update from [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

*If* you want to switch to Linq to Entities then yes, you will need VS2010.

Or you can stay with VS2005/2008 and use nHibernate or similar framework.
But none of those ORM tools is (primarily) about speed, so it may not be the right thing for you.

The reasons for switching to an ORM framework would be to use a more OOP approach, ie to replace your generic list.

Look through a few demos/walkthroughs to decide if it is something for you.

Comment: LINQ to Entities doesn't require VS 2010, does it? Admittedly the latest version will, but the previous version should be fine with VS 2008, AFAIK.

Comment: @Jon, yes, but I would not recommend the first EF version, or upgrading to VS2008 anymore.

Comment: @Henk: That's fair enough, but it's not the same as saying "If you want to switch to L2E, you will need VS2010" :) (There may be other reasons why the OP *can't* use VS2010, but he may be able to use 2008 and EF may still be the best approach.)

Comment: He can also use LINQ to SQL which is included in .NET 3.5. I think you need Visual Studio 2008 to be able to use its designer.

Comment: @Jon, correct but very hypothetical. If I can't use VS2010 for something, I won't use EF. @Steven: That is one of the 'similar' frameworks. The list is longer.

Comment: why does using a version of EF have dependency on VS version? Isn't it a bad idea?

Comment: @Henk, Can you pls elaborate on this "If I can't use VS2010 for something, I won't use EF."

Comment: EF4 requires dotNet4 and dotNet4 requires VS2010. The first version of EF left a lot to be desired. If you're limited to VS2008 I would recommend L2S or nHibernate. But that is subjective.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to write up your requirements, then identify the options, evaluate each option with some tests that are meaningful for your requirements (e.g. ease of use, speed, etc.), and finally decide. With some smart design and implementation choices you might even be able to switch between some of them with relatively limited effort at least at the beginning.

The Entity Framework is certainly an option. I'd recommend to also include NHibernate and in particular [fluent-nhibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) in your investigation. Good luck!

Comment: I have to agree - there is a lot to commend EF and NHibernate and various other options but every single option is a compromise, as soon as you use an ORM or any other technology between the client code and the database you are going to start to add overhead (i.e. loss of performance) *however* in the real world the loss of performance is more often than not insignificant and the benefits to the developer considerable. You need to decide what you want to do first (i.e. do you want to change your db access philosophy) and then look at your options.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider performance, see here

http://toomanylayers.blogspot.com/2009/01/entity-framework-and-linq-to-sql.html

http://blog.codefluententities.com/2012/06/05/codefluent-entities-performance-comparison/

Traditional ADO.NET (without ORM) is the fastest way. If efficiency is a key issue then better stay with "SqlDataReader".

Answer (score 0):

Writing the queries yourself still beats any automatic process performance-wise. Entity framework makes the data layer more abstract, which improves portability and readability.